# LogicException: Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled

Tags: laravel, redis, predis, laravel-7, laravel-events

Laravel Version: 7.5.0
PHP Version: 7.2
Database Driver & Version: Redis

Everything was working fine but suddenly this error appear i changed the phpredis to predis but error is same.

Steps To Reproduce:
I am calling the event function `event(new ChatsEvent($data));`

```
LogicException: Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled. in /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:76
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(428): Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector->Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis))
#1 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(104): tap(Object(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis), Object(Closure))
#2 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(27): Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector->createClient(Array)
#3 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(31): Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector->Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\{closure}()
#4 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisManager.php(111): Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector->connect(Array, Array)
#5 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisManager.php(90): Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager->resolve('default')
#6 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/RedisBroadcaster.php(108): Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager->connection('default')
#7 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php(64): Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\RedisBroadcaster->broadcast(Array, 'ChatsEvent', Array)
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent->handle(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\RedisBroadcaster))
#9 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(36): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#11 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#12 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#13 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(592): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#14 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#15 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#16 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#17 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#18 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(83): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent), false)
#19 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\Queue\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#20 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#21 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(85): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#22 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(59): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#23 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(98): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#24 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(356): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#25 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(306): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#26 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(132): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#27 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(112): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#28 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(96): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#29 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#30 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#31 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(36): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#32 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#33 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#34 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(592): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#35 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(134): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#36 /home/user/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#37 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#38 /home/user/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(912): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#39 /home/user/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(264): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#40 /home/user/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(140): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#41 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#42 /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#43 /home/user/public_html/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#44 {main}
```

Comment: I just had the same happen! Application was running fine for weeks, including with Redis setup up property, and all of sudden this morning:

`LogicException
Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled.`

How did you sort it out? Did your error also happen out of the blue?

Answer (score 70):

In case you install Redis with `composer require predis/predis`, you need to add this line to `.env` file:

```
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
```

Then clear cache by run this command: `php artisan optimize:clear`

---

`An additional way` you can change this line in `config/database.php` file:

From:

```
'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
```

To:

```
'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
```

Then clear cache by run this command: `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Or you can add REDIS_CLIENT=predis to your .env file

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Editing `config/database.php` solved my problem.

Answer (score 28):

For My case I just install php extension in my ubuntu server which is in below

```
sudo apt-get install php-redis
```

Comment: The single normal answer

Comment: exactly this ^^

Answer (score 16):

If you're in windows add the dependency of predis using this `composer require predis/predis` command.
Then configure your .env file like this

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

I'm using redis for queueing my mail's.So I set `QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis` and `REDIS_CLIENT=predis`.This works fine when you're developing locally .In production its same but little bit different

Comment: note that this is `predis` (PHP package written in PHP) not `PhpRedis` (Written in C) which is faster than `predis`.

Answer (score 15):

Php redis extension is missing.

There are two ways:

1. Install php redis extension (answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61325340/3578207)
2. Change driver to predis (`REDIS_CLIENT` in .env) and install [predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) composer package (`composer require predis/predis`).

But `predis` little bit slower that `phpredis`.

P.S.: (for way number 1): After installing phpredis extension you need to add this to `composer.json` into `require` section as `"ext-redis": "*"` for proper deployments. See about [composer platform requirements](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#check-platform-reqs).

Comment: I am using windows machine and unable to run pecl install redis .getting error

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PEAR\REST.php on line 186
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/redis"
install failed

Comment: @zlodes thank you very much. The `"ext-redis": "*"` was the solution for my problem. But could you please explain me why this is needed? I have installed `redis` via `pecl` and added `extension="redis.so"` to my `php.ini`. I always got the error `Please make sure Redis is installed`. Any idea? I just want to understand the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I have some problem dude, but i was solved this problem. Try and learn (My OS is Linux):

**Step 1**: Install PhpRedis
In order to install the latest version of the PhpRedis extension, we can use pecl. To install pecl you need to install the PHP Extension and Application Repository or PEAR for short:

```
sudo apt install php-pear
```

**Step 2**: Then you might also have to install the PHP Dev tools:

```
sudo apt install php-dev
```

**Step 3**: Then we would want to go ahead and install this package here. To do that, just run:

```
sudo pecl install redis
```

**Finally**: Make sure that you enable the new PHP extension by adding the following line to your php.ini and if you are not finded this script, you can write this script under the list of all `extension=`

```
extension = redis.io
```

And don't forget to restart your apache2 service by:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

*Good luck dude!*

Comment: After running `sudo pecl install redis` there is a description which says **You have to add extension=redis.so** but in your answer it is `redis.io`, what's the difference between `extension=redis.io` and `extension=redis.so`?

Answer (score 1):

I always end up facing trouble installing `php7.x-dev` like this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.3-dev : Depends: libpcre2-dev (>= 10.30) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php7.3-common (= 7.3.11-0ubuntu0.19.10.6) but 7.3.20-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
              Recommends: pkg-php-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I skip `php7.x-dev` installation and go straight to `sudo pecl install redis` then I got new Error:

```
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I endup searching for installing `phpize` and the solution is to install `php-dev`.

for those of you have similiar problem like me. instead of `sudo apt-get install php7.x-dev` use `sudo aptitude install php7.x-dev`

### Install aptitude

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

then run `sudo apt-install php7.x-dev` and then if prompt ask if you want to *Keep the following packages at their current version:*

select **NO** this will auto downgrade or upgrade the version in order to install `php7.x-dev`.

Next step install redis:

```
sudo pecl install --force redis
```

> Note: The –force flag makes sure the extension is added regardless of
> any cached settings that may prevent installation.

Then You should add `"extension=redis.so"` to **php.ini**. in my case **php.ini** is located in `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini`

And restart apache2 by running this command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

if you have not install `php-fpm` run this command.

```
sudo apt install php7.3-fpm
```

**Note:** that you need to restart the `php artisan serve`. this because laravel will not recognize PHP Redis even if you are successfully installed package (redis, php-dev) so keep in mind restart the php artisan serve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Heroku or another PaaS platform, there is a high chance that you need to add Redis extension to your composer requirements:

```
"ext-redis": "*",
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 8.

Old Laravel 5.2 settings were:

```
'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

Settings for Laravel 8, which are working fine now:

```
'redis' => [
        
    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem goes out after reboot of the server and nothing more, u don't need to install or reinstall anything just reboot, that's the secret matter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Laravel updated version ~8 THEN:

you have to change in 2 files:

File 1:
replace 'phpredis' with 'predis' in /bootstrap/cache/config.php

```
'redis' => 
    array (
        'client' => 'predis', //you might have 'phpredis'
```

File 2:
replace 'phpredis' with 'predis' in /config/database.php

```
    'redis' => [
    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
```

My problem was solved by that