# How to enable Redis connection in PHPUnit in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redis, phpunit

I have a Laravel application that uses mysql as its main database and I also use some redis connection on some parts for faster loading of data.

Currently I'm creating unit tests using phpunit in laravel. However the method that I'm trying to create unit test with has redis connection - `Redis::connection()`. The expected assertion should be a 200 response but because of that redis connection it is returning 500 response. How can I enable redis on php unit so I can create a unit test for it?

my current `phpunit.xml` are configured like this:

```
<php>
   <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
   <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
   <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
   <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
   <server name="DB_DATABASE" value="MY_DB_NAME"/>
   <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
   <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
   <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
</php>
```

Here's the error log:

```
[2021-03-29 12:12:53] testing.ERROR: Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled. {"userId":84,"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled. at /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:77)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(433): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\PhpRedisConnector->Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Redis))
#1 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(105): tap(Object(Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Redis), Object(Closure))
#2 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(28): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\PhpRedisConnector->createClient(Array)
#3 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(32): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\PhpRedisConnector->Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#4 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisManager.php(110): Illuminate\\Redis\\Connectors\\PhpRedisConnector->connect(Array, Array)
#5 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisManager.php(90): Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisManager->resolve('default')
#6 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisManager->connection()
#7 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/app/Http/Controllers/DataContentOfficerController.php(419): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('connection', Array)
#8 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\DataContentOfficerController->manual_qc_confirm()
#9 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('manual_qc_confi...', Array)
#10 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(239): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\DataContentOfficerController), 'manual_qc_confi...')
#11 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(196): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#12 /home/johndoe/bo2-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(685): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
...
```

Comment: Since there's no redis configuration in your phpunit.xml it will use the default configuration from `config/cache.php` so make sure that is correct as well.

Comment: @apokryfos under config/cache.php here's the redis config..`'redis' => ['driver' => 'redis','connection' => 'cache'],` is it correct?

Comment: Oops. I forgot that they moved this some time ago. It's now in `config/databases.php` under `redis`. I would imagine the connection used by default is the one under `default`

Comment: ahh yes it is configured correctly based on its .env values

Comment: Are the `.env` values read? I thought they weren't in favour of `phpunit.xml` values

Comment: in normal page load..it was read..but in phpunit it is not being read I think? because it returns 500 response when I'm trying to have redis connection

Comment: so may be there's something I need to configure on phpunit.xml to enable redis..that's what I'm asking

Comment: Lines in the config like e.g. `env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1')` that if the environment variable `REDIS_HOST` is set, use that otherwise fallback to `127.0.0.1` basically if the fallback is correct then you don't need to set anything in your environment variables, however in the cases where it's not you need to set the environment variable in `phpunit.xml` like e.g. `<server name="REDIS_CLIENT" value="predis"/>` if you aren't using phpredis

Comment: As I said, on normal page load redis was read and redis content was loaded successfully. It means that the config is set and correct, right? its just that when I run the test case I created in phpunit the line `Redis::connection()` causes the 500 response.

Comment: could you write the error log stack trace?

Comment: generating in `/storage/log`

Comment: @Abilogos added the error log on the question. It seems like it is not detecting PHP Redis on phpunit but it is working on normal mode

Answer (score 2):

If your local (the `.env` work) you should create one `.env.testing` and do PHPUnit tests using the `--env=testing`  option like it says in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing#the-env-testing-environment-file).

Comment: yes I did this already. but still redis is still not working

Comment: I see from log error "Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled". You should follow that problem on this [question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168156/logicexception-please-make-sure-the-php-redis-extension-is-installed-and-enable)